# making Google API JSLint compliant

Tags: google-api, jslint

Trying to put a Google login button on my page. Their example code is not passing JSLint test.

I've gone through one iteration of edits (thanks @ruffin!), but now the problem is expanding, so I've edited this post to include more.

```
/*global Kobo,$,ko,Modernizr,GeneralConfiguration, gapi, eventHandlers */

Kobo.Utilities.AuthorizedAction = function (actionURL) {
    "use strict";

    var renderButton;

    renderButton = function () {
        gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'width': 236,
            'height': 44,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'dark',
            'onsuccess': window.eventHandlers.onSuccess,
            'onfailure': window.eventHandlers.onFailure
        });
    };

    if (Kobo.$.cookie('store.kobobooks.com') || Kobo.$.cookie('store.dev.koboboooks.com') || Kobo.$.cookie('storeperf.kobobooks.com')) {
        window.location.href = actionURL;
    } else {
        var content = Kobo.$('#reg-content');
        renderButton();
        Kobo._modal.open(content);
    }
};

// Google sign in


function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    "use strict";

    //var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      //console.log(googleUser);
      //console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
      //console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
      //console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
      //console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
      //console.log('https://securehd15.kobobooks.com/auth/Google/connect?rst=False&ReturnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
    window.location.href = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fplus.login+email+profile&client_id=642155554319-85mk1095rdhahgsssi9hm217eh461mld.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fsecureqa.kobobooks.com%2fauth%2fGoogle%2fgoogleoauth2callback&state=https://storehd.kobobooks.com/?utm_source=Reviewer&utm_source=reviewer';
}


window.eventHandlers = window.eventHandlers || {};

window.eventHandlers.onSuccess = function () {
    "use strict";
    window.alert('some code');
};
window.eventHandlers.onFailure = function () {
    "use strict";
    window.alert('some more code');
};
```

It builds OK but at render time I get

```
<exception>: ReferenceError: gapi is not defined at renderButton
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, `gapi` is the API's "namespace", and is at the global context, so that's easy to fix. It also looks like the second parameter is just object notation, so the single quotes for var names are extraneous.

So let's put `gapi` in our `global` directive.

```
/*jslint white:true */
/*global gapi */
function renderButton() {
  "use strict";

  gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    width: 236,
    height: 44,
    longtitle: true,
    theme: 'dark',
    onsuccess: onSuccess,
    onfailure: onFailure
  });
}
```

You'll still get those errors about `onSuccess` and `onFailure`, however, **and you should**, if they're not defined in the file. You need to either define those two functions in the same file as this call, or, better yet, put them into your own namespace, and import that in globals.

That is, in one file, you can define what those event handlers are, and put them into a global namespace `eventHandlers` (check the `window` trick I'm doing there):

```
/*jslint white:true */
/*global window */
window.eventHandlers = window.eventHandlers || {};

window.eventHandlers.onSuccess = function () {
    "use strict";
    window.alert('some code');
};
window.eventHandlers.onFailure = function () {
    "use strict";
    window.alert('some more code');
};
```

Then tell JSLint that the `eventHandlers` namespace exists in this file.

```
/*jslint white:true */
/*global gapi, eventHandlers */
function renderButton() {
  "use strict";

  gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    width: 236,
    height: 44,
    longtitle: true,
    theme: 'dark',
    onsuccess: eventHandlers.onSuccess,
    onfailure: eventHandlers.onFailure
  });
}
```

That lints.